# How to set X-Frame-Options in laravel project?

Tags: html, laravel, iframe, websecurity, clickjacking

I want to prevent my website from clickJacking attack. In which file and where to set X-Frame-Options for preventing clickJacking attack.

Comment: here is a solution that shows how to set `X-Frame-Options` https://gist.github.com/EduardoSP6/221c75332de2dbebebe98bf51f80ddb5

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have 2 ways:

- Setup it in a reverse proxy such as Nginx

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

- Use Laravel middleware `Illuminate\Http\Middleware\FrameGuard` onto the routes you want to protect.

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FrameGuard
{
    /**
     * Handle the given request and get the response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I got the same problem. I tried this approach (FrameGuard), but I still get `Refused to display ... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`, Missing something?

Comment: @HMihail It sounds like you want to do the opposite of what the OP is trying to do. (Allow an iframe from a different domain instead of preventing it from all but the same domain.)

Comment: does this works for api routes as well? I have SPA app.

Comment: It is useless against JSON routes, only HTML ones, so it would be useful against your only HTML route

Answer (score 4):

To fix the problem on all your routes :

Add `FrameGuard::class,` on the `protected $middleware` in your `app/http/Kernel.php`

FrameGuard.php by default is set to `"SAMEORIGIN"`, but you can change the second parameter of the following line with `"DENY"` or `"ALLOW-FROM uri"` (according to your needs) :

`$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the `Content-Security-Policy` header in the `.htaccess` file of your project if you're using an Apache server. However, the policy you've set `frame-ancestors *;` allows the page to be embedded from any origin. If you want to restrict it to the same origin, you should use `self` instead of `*`. Here's how you can do it:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"
</IfModule>
```

This will only allow the page to be embedded in an iframe on the same origin. Please replace `'self'` with your specific domain if you want to allow specific origins.